# Google Calendar API: can i retrieve entries changed/created after a specified date?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Can i retrieve entries changed/created after a specified date? This is regardless of the event date - only by "modified date". I.e. if i modify an old even i want to be able to retrieve it using a query (without knowing its id)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself but according to the documentation you should be able to access all events updated within a certain range using the standard Data API query parameters **updated-min** and **updated-max**.

See: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters
and: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html#QueryRequests

I'm not sure if you are using a code library to access the Google Calendar API so I cannot comment further.